# Using sets of arguments from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, map

Please Consider :

```
list={{5,2,6},{2,8,3}}
```

I need to get the product of all the element within list :

As of now I do this :

```
(#[[1]]*#[[2]]*#[[3]]) & /@ list
```

Which means I have to manually specify the number of elements within each least and the sublists length has to b equal.

How could do this automatically to automatically deal with the following case ?

```
listA={{5,2,6,3},{2,8,3,4}}
listB={{5,2,6},{2,4}}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use Apply at the first level:

```
Times @@@ listA
```

Answer (score 22):

**Short answer:** See [Heike's post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1971/103).

**Longer version:**

There are a couple of functions in the functional programming toolbox that are so common that they've gotten their own symbols. One of them is [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html), which takes a list and uses its elements as function arguments:

```
Apply[f, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> f[a, b, c]
> ```

The shorthand notation for this would be `f @@ {a, b, c}`.

Additionally, `Apply` has an optinal third argument, specifying the depth at which the function should be applied:

```
(* Apply on 0-th level *)
Apply[f, {{a,b}, {c,d}}]
```

> ```
> f[{a,b}, {c,d}]
> ```

```
(* Apply on the first level *)
Apply[f, {{a,b}, {c,d}}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {f[a,b], f[c,d]}
> ```

The latter is also a very common expression, it has the shorthand notation `f @@@ {{a,b}, {c,d}}`. The notation ends here, i.e. there's no `@@@@`; if you need that, you'll have to use `Apply` explicitly. The documentation features plenty of examples if you need further help.

That said, what you want is converting a list of lists of numbers to a list of the product of the numbers. This is equivalent to applying the product function on the first level of the original list; that function is called `Times` in Mathematica (`Product` stands for the mathematical expression $\prod_a^bx$). `Times` is the internal function that is called when you enter something like `a*b*c`: it becomes `Times[a,b,c]` internally. Therefore, using the `Apply` function from above,

```
Apply[Times, {{a,b}, {c,d}}, {1}]

(* Evaluates to ... *)
{Times[a,b], Times[c,d]}

(* ... and is equivalent to ... *)
{a b, c d}
```

That's precisely what you want. Adding the syntactic sugar from above, `@@@`, this leaves you with the final short notation

```
Times @@@ list
```

to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank You very much for the Detailed explanation

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun:

```
Replace[list, {x__} :> 1 x, 1]
```

Since this answer has garnered some votes here is a more direct form of the implicit `Times`:

```
1##& @@@ list
```

Comment: Nice. Implicitly passing `x` to `Times` by prefixing it with a 1, and because it is a `Sequence` it becomes `Times[1, x]`. Very clever.

Comment: @rcollyer thank you :-)

Comment: I think, the implicit version should be `1##& @@ list` - with `@@` instead of `@@@`. `1##& @@@ list` will apply Times on nesting level 1 instead of 0, and will therefore simply return the unchanged list.

Comment: @JimiLoe I wish to always be open to correction, but in this case I do not believe I made a mistake.  `1 ## & @@@ {{5, 2, 6}, {2, 8, 3}}` evaluates to `{60, 48}` which is the same as the original code `(#[[1]]*#[[2]]*#[[3]]) & /@ {{5, 2, 6}, {2, 8, 3}}`.  `1 ## & @@ {{5, 2, 6}, {2, 8, 3}}` evaluates to `{10, 16, 18}` which is a different result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right. I tested it with a flat list and not a nested one. Thank you for your quick response!