# How to substitute values from a list into a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I was hoping to take pairs of numbers from a list and substitute them into a function. So if my list was

```
list = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}
```

and my function was

```
function = a x^b
```

The output I'm hoping to get is

```
result =1x^2 + 3x^4 + 5x^6
```

How would I best do this?

Comment: `#1 x^#2 & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} // Total`

Comment: You might find [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) useful.

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/using-sets-of-arguments-from-a-list

Answer (score 8):

This is not a `Function`:

```
function = a x^b
```

But this is:

```
function = {a,b} \[Function] a x^b
```

You can `Apply` it to each element of

```
list = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}
```

with

```
function @@@ list
```

> {x^3, 3 x^5, 5 x^7}

and sum it up with `Total`:

```
Total[ function @@@ list ]
```

> x^3 + 3 x^5 + 5 x^7

Comment: Why would you do 'function = {a,b} \[Function] a x^b' instead of function[a_, b_, x_] = a*x^b?

Comment: Because `\[Function]` is easily entered with the escape sequence esc f n esc . Also `Function` defines a _pure function_ while `function[a_, b_, x_] = a*x^b` defines a replacement rule. However, they act the same way - most of the time. So it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Pineapple Take a look at this tutorial on [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html). Another good resource is the tutorial on [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) for the difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`).

Comment: If you want a pure function, why not go with `function = # x^#2 &`?

Comment: @GregMartin Simply because I am a mathematician: I am more familiar with the $\mapsto$-syntax. Actually, I find the $\lambda$-calculus very hard to read, in particular when you try to produce functions that generate functions as their result.

Answer (score 7):

```
Total[#*x^#2&@@@list]
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

Answer (score 5):

Another way, perhaps easier on the eyes. Use a pattern to deconstruct the pairs in a function definition.

```
term[{a_, b_}] := a x^b
```

Then, `Map` it to the list.

```
Total[term /@ list]
(* x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Supposing

```
function = a x^b
```

is already set and can't be changed.  How to do what the OP wants?

One way to is to use `ReplaceAll`:

```
function /. Thread[{a, b} -> Transpose@list] // Total
(*  x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6  *)
```

Another standard method is to use `Block`:

```
Block[{a, b},
 {a, b} = Transpose@list;
 Total@function
 ]
(*  x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6  *)
```

If you like the functional solutions presented by others, `function` can be turned into a pure function as follows:

```
fn = Function @@ {{a, b}, function}       (* or *)
fn = Function[{a, b}, Evaluate@function]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Total[(#[[1]] x^#[[2]]) & /@ list]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Sorry - I'm very new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[fa, fb]
fa = FromCoefficientRules[Thread[#[[All, 2;;]] -> #[[All, 1]]], #2] &;
fb = Internal`FromCoefficientList[Normal@SparseArray[1 + #[[All, 2;;]]->#[[All, 1]]], #2] &;
```

Examples:

```
list1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
{fa[list1, x], fb[list1, x]}
```

> {x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6, x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6}

```
list2 = {{1, 3, 0}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3}};
{fa[list2, {x, y}], fb[list2, {x, y}]}
```

> {x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + y^3, x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + y^3}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
list /. {a_, i_} -> a x^i // Total
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Apply[# . x^#2 &] @* Transpose;

f @ list
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

and

```
☺ = # x^#2&@@@#&/*Tr;
☺ @ list
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

```
☺☺ = +## & @@ (# x^#2 & @@@ #) &;
☺☺ @ list
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

```
☺☺☺ = #.x^#2 & @@ (#\[Transpose])&;
☺☺☺ @ list
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

Answer (score 1):

```
Inner[#1 x^#2 &, Sequence @@ Transpose@list, Plus]
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

One could expand this a bit to allow for different variables:

```
Clear[f]
f[coefflist_][var_] := Inner[#1 var^#2 &, Sequence @@ Transpose@coefflist, Plus]
```

so that

```
f[list][x]
```

> x^2 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^6

but then:

```
f[list][t]
```

> t^2 + 3 t^4 + 5 t^6