# Overloading a function to pass in an expression rather that the name of a function

Tags: function-construction, syntax, procedural-programming

This is an example of procedural programming borrowed from Paul Wellin's book. It's a simple implementation of the Newton-Rhapson method.

I overloaded the `findRoot` function to accommodate different kinds of arguments. It works fine in the following first case:

```
findRoot[fun_Symbol, {var_, init_}, ϵ_] := 
   Module[{xi = init},
     While[Abs[fun[xi]] > ϵ, xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
     {var -> xi}]

f[x_] := x^2 - 2;

findRoot[f,{x,2},.0001]
```

> ```
> {x-> 1.41422}
> ```

But when I overload it to accommodate expressions, like the following for example, it doesn't evaluate.

```
findRoot[expr_== val_, {var_, init_}, ϵ_] := 
  Module[{xi = init, fun = Function[fvar,expr - val]},
    While[Abs[fun[xi]] > ϵ, xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
    {var -> xi}]

findRoot[x^2 - 2 == 0, {x, 2.0}, 0.0001]
```

> ```
> {x - >2.}
> ```

How do I make Mathematica evaluate it numerically all the way through?

Comment: Try `fun = Function[fvar, Evaluate[expr - val]]` -- This technique used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192708/4999) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169338/4999)

Comment: @Michael E2 Still doesn't work but thanks.

Comment: I think there's a typo: `var` should replace `fvar` in your/my codes.  Also `Nest` (or `FixedPoint`) could be used instead of `While`, if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little tricky because Mathematica renames the variable given in the 1st argument of `Function` to localize it. So the renaming has to be taken into account when substituting the desired variable into `Function`. The unevaluated locally defined `fun` is then passed to the previously defined version of `findRoot` and all goes well.

```
findRoot[expr_ == val_, {var_, init_}, ϵ_] :=
  Module[{fun},
    fun = Function[u, expr - val] /. u$ -> var;
    findRoot[Unevaluated[fun], {var, init}, ϵ]]
```

Note: I pass `Unevaluated[fun]` to the previously defined version of `findRoot` because that function requires it's 1st argument to be a symbol.

```
findRoot[x^2 - 2 == 0, {x, 2.0}, 0.0001]
```

> `{x -> 1.41422}`

Another useful test is to write the equation as `x^2 == 2`.

```
findRoot[x^2 == 2, {x, 2.0}, 0.0001]
```

> `{x -> 1.41422}`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `$` in `u$`?

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho. It's there because, behind the scenes, Mathematica changes the `u` in `Function[u, expr - val]` to `Function[u$, expr - val]`, so that is what the replacement has to match. That is what I was discussing in the 1st paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho. I have updated my answer with an explanation of why I pass  `Unevaluated[fun]` to the original `findRoot`.

Answer (score 2):

From my comment, with the OP's typo, which I did not notice, fixed:

```
findRoot[expr_ == val_, {var_, init_}, \[Epsilon]_] := 
 Module[{xi = init,
   fun = Function[var, Evaluate[expr - val]]},
  While[Abs[fun[xi]] > \[Epsilon],
   xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
  {var -> xi}]

findRoot[x^2 == 2, {x, 1.}, 10^-8]
(*  {x -> 1.41421}  *)
```

If you want the variable `var` to be protected from evaluation inside `findRoot`, just as it is in `FindRoot`, you can do the following:

```
ClearAll[findRoot];
SetAttributes[findRoot, HoldAll];
findRoot[expr_ == val_, {var_, init_}, \[Epsilon]_] := 
 Module[{xi = init,
   fun = Function @@ Hold[var, expr - val]},
  While[Abs[fun[xi]] > \[Epsilon],
   xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
  {var -> xi}];
```

Then the following finds the root, just like `FindRoot`, but just like `FindRoot`, `x` is evaluated after the solution is returned.  This could be prevented by returning `{HoldPattern[var] -> xi}` instead of `{var -> xi}`, but `FindRoot` does not do it.

```
x = 2;
findRoot[x^2 == 2, {x, 1.}, 10^-8]
(*  {2 -> 1.41421}  *)
```

As @m_goldberg's answer shows, it's good to have one core routine and have all the interfaces call it.  Here's another way but putting the core routine in an "internal" function:

```
ClearAll[findRoot, iFindRoot];
iFindRoot[fun_, dfun_, init_, \[Epsilon]_] := Module[{xi = init},
   While[Abs[fun[xi]] > \[Epsilon],
    xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/dfun[xi]]];
   xi];
findRoot[fun : _Symbol | _Function, {var_, 
    init_?NumericQ}, \[Epsilon]_] :=
  {var -> 
    iFindRoot[fun, fun', init, \[Epsilon]]};
findRoot[fun : _Symbol | _Function, {init_?
     NumericQ}, \[Epsilon]_] :=
  {iFindRoot[fun, fun', 
    init, \[Epsilon]]};
findRoot[expr_ == val_, {var_, init_?NumericQ}, \[Epsilon]_] := 
  Module[{fun},
   fun = Function[var, Evaluate[expr - val]];
   {var -> iFindRoot[fun, fun', init, \[Epsilon]]}];
```

Comment: I noticed that in both answers, your function starting with `ClearAll[findRoot];` and m_goldberg's, you preclude `fun` from evaluating. However, seems to me for different reasons (I could be wrong!). m_goldberg uses Unevaluated to pass an unevaluated function to the first defined version of `findRoot`. You use `HoldAll` and `Hold` to prevent `var` from evaluating inside `findRoot`. Why is this prevention important?

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho Some *Mathematica* functions effectively localize their argument variables so that the remain symbols. For instance, `x = 2; FindRoot[x^2 == 2, {x, 1.}]` will find the right root even though `x^2 == 2` would evaluate to `False` if evaluated when `x` equaled `2`. The use of `Hold` in the 2nd alternative definition prevents `x` and the sides of the equation from evaluating, using `Function` to localize the argument `var`. It's also important the `findRoot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. See also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html