# Map and Pure Function

Tags: list-manipulation

Trying to take the first item of a member and raising it to the power of the second item of the same member and then subtracting the output from the third item of the same member, the list:

```
{{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}
```

I got to as far as:

```
list = {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}
p = Map[#[[1]] &, list];
```

Comment: #[[3]]  - #[[1]]^#[[2]] &  /@ {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}

Comment: Looks a lot like 214438

Comment: `{#3-#1^#2}&@@@your_list//Flatten`

Comment: @user1066 drop `{}` and `Flatten`.

Comment: related: [1974](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1974/5478)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is

```
list = {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}
Cases[list, {x_, y_, z_} :> x^y - z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which I think is a little bit more readable than map

```
list = {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}
#[[1]]^#[[2]] - #[[3]] & /@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option is

```
Function[{x, y, z}, (x^y) - z] @@@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think you have to multiply your results by `-1`. The question says that the power should be subtracted from the third element.

Comment: One potential complication when using `Cases` for this purpose is that it does not necessarily preserve the order of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

In case you would prefer a tacit or declarative version:

```
{{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}} // (
    Map[{Last, Most /* Apply[Power]} /* Through /* Apply[Subtract]]
)
(* {4, -1, -4093} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mat={{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}};
Table[mat[[i,3]]-(mat[[i,1]]^mat[[i,2]]),{i,3}]
```

Or

```
Table[mat[[i,3]]-(mat[[i,1]]^mat[[i,2]]),{i,Length[mat]}]
```